# JavaScript variable property?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that dynamically sets properties based on parameters,

it looks like this

```
function setPro(sourceId,type,destId){
    document.getElementById(destId).style. + type = document.getElementById(sourceId).value;

}
```

I'm not sure what to do on setting the type?

is this possible? or am I going to have to do a select case and choose based on that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `[]` notation:

```
document.getElementById(destId).style[type] = document.getElementById(sourceId).value;
```